# Odoo Override create function works but return dictionary eroor

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to override the create and write method from Odoo.
My code (below) hits the error indicated:

```
 class sms(models.Model):


    _description = "Module d'envoi et de reception SMS"
    contenu = fields.Text("Contenu", required=True)
    date_sms = fields.Datetime(string="Date", default=lambda *a: datetime.now(), required=True)
    type = fields.Char(string="Type", readonly=True, default="envoi")
    status = fields.Char(string="Status", required=True, default="brouillon", readonly=True)
    destinataire_ids = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='hr.employee',
        relation="m2m_mission_employee_relation",
        column1="m2m_id",
        column2="id",
        string="Destinataire", required=True) 
    num = fields.Char(string="Numero") 

    @api.onchange('destinataire_ids')
    def _set_number(self):  
        for record in self:
            record.num = self.destinataire_ids.mobile_phone
            self.num = self.destinataire_ids.mobile_phone

    def get_user_id(self):
        context = self._context
        current_uid = context.get('uid')
        user = self.env['res.users'].browse(current_uid)
        return  user

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        res = super(sms, self).write(vals)

    @api.model 
    def create(self,values): 
        campus_create = super(sms, self).create(values)
        return campus_create
```

The error hit was:

```
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\odoo-11.0.post20180130-py3.5.egg\odoo\models.py", line 1536, in _add_missing_default_values
    defaults.update(values)
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
***TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence***
```

Comment: Could please add more info? A bigger stack trace would be helpful. And which Odoo version are you working with? And besides the first answer's hint of the missing `_inherit`, why is there no return in your `write`?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you say what model you are overriding?

Try put `_inherit = 'model'` on start of your class